# Can I publish a feed of my Meetups to appear on my Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, meetup

I'm a bit of a Meetup junkie so I'd like to automate the appearance of any Meetup I RSVP to automagically appear on my Google Calendar.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes.  Here's how:

When you are logged in, on the right side of the home page at [www.meetup.com](http://www.meetup.com), underneath the calendar widget, you should see an **Export** link.

After clicking on it, click the **Google calendar** link in the drop down, and it should bring up your Google Calendar page with a popup asking: **Do you want to add this calendar?**

Click the button: **Yes, add this calendar**, and you are now added your Meetup subscription to your Google Calendar.

You should then see all meetups you are attending as a subscription.

Note that your new Meetup/Google calendar will not be updated by Meetup to reflect edited or cancelled events, or if you change your rsvp, and there is no way to remove such events from that calendar.

Comment: Seems like this link might be missing in the new UI.  Anyone find a new way?

Comment: Meetup has a page describing their current (May 2014) feeds here: http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/feeds/

Comment: Can anyone confirm that edited or cancelled events don't update the iCal feed?

Comment: This only exports Meetups you've said you're going to

Answer (score 5):

I had to replace the **http://** prefix with **webcal://** to make it work for me (March 2014).

The straightforward **"Export to..."** from Meetup.com posted by Jo Liss did create a **My Meetups** calendar, only it is empty... For anyone having the same issue as I had, here is what I did:

The Diagnosis: when you open the newly-created calendar, you will notice it uses http:// prefix:

- Left pane, under **Other Calendars**, look for the newly created calendar - mine was default-called **My Meetups**
- Right of **My Meetups**, click the down arrow, select **Calendar Settings** to open the **My Meetups** Details page.
- The **URL** field looks like this:
  http://www.meetup.com/events/ical/YOUR_CALENDAR_ID/going

The Fix: Since the URL cannot be modified from the Details page, what I did is:

- copy the above URL
- go **Back to calendar**
- Left pane, right of **Other Calendars**, click on the down arrow, select **Add by URL**
- Paste the URL. Replace "http://" with "webcal://" at the beginning of it so that your URL now reads webcal://www.meetup.com/events/ical/YOUR_CALENDAR_ID/going
- Clik **Add Calendar**

That's it! Now the events I'm attending on Meetup.com are actually showing up in my Google Calendar. Hope this helps

Comment: Using webcal:// instead of http:// worked for me as well:
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/b/1/r?cid=webcal://www.meetup.com/

Answer (score 0):

Currently (November 2013) your event calendar is on the home page of meetup.com when you are logged in. From there you can select which events you want to have in your personalized calendar, and there is an option to export it to Google Calendar.

Answer (score -1):

### Sync meetup dot com to Google calendar

1. get API Key(see img)
2. get User ID (see img)
3. go to Google Clander (see img)
4. Add the link from step 5
5. http://www.meetup.com/events/ical/*****USER ID*********/*****API Key*********/going

[image]

Comment: If the exact same answer applies to multiple questions, that's a big clue that they're duplicates.

Comment: thank you for your support , how should i deal with duplicated questions ?

Comment: This was the only answer that helped me.  I didn't need steps 1 and 2 because the link Meetup provides (under the calendar on the home page) contains the correct URL (but with %2F where it should have /).  Thanks Mohamed!