# Automatically sync Meetup events with Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, meetup

Is there anyway to automatically have my [Meetup](http://www.meetup.com/) event calendar sync up with Google Calendar, or even Outlook?

### Update

I want to do this for all of my groups at once (not each individual group)

Comment: See also http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3628/can-i-publish-a-feed-of-my-meetups-to-appear-on-my-google-calendar (possible dup).

Comment: I've tried pretty much every solution I've found on the web, and none of them have worked for me. I've resigned myself to exporting each event manually when I RSVP.

Answer (score 13):

You can add *Your meetup calendar* to Google Calendar accessable over your personal home page.

[image]

[Information](https://www.meetup.com/help/article/868938/)

Comment: It seems this hasn't worked for some time now. Even though my personal calendar (with suggestions turned off) shows items, the calendar URL shows no entries. To emphasize, it *did* work some time ago. Ditto for the "RSVP'd Yes" calendar.

Comment: The basic idea still works (2014). The calendar is on the front page of meetup when you're logged in. It has an "export to" link that does the job.

Comment: The link in this answer is broken now. Can the link be updated so that it points to the correct page?

Comment: I'm able to sync the events I already signed up for. But can I also sync upcoming events somehow?

Comment: I WROTE THIS. I hated the way meetup handled this so I wrote a python script that scrapes out all meetup events for all the meetup groups you're in. You can host it on heroku yourself, and it shouldn't be too painful even if you're not technical. Hope this helps someone :D 

https://github.com/davidawad/meetup_ical_export

Answer (score 11):

If you look at the bottom of the calendar page for whatever [Meetup](http://www.meetup.com/) group you are looking for you'll see an **iCal** link to subscribe to.

Copy this link and within Google Calendar you can add a new calendar **From URL**.

Paste the link and click **Add Calendar > From URL** and you should be good to go.

edit: Make sure you use the **From URL** submenu.

Comment: i wanted to see if there was a way to do it for all of my groups at once . .

Comment: do you know if this possible to do this for all collective meetings at once?

Comment: "edit: This no longer seems to be possible on Meetup.com" It is at the bottom of your meetup's calendar area, right-click and copy the link on the text "ical". Thanks for the good answer "quickcel", but it won't let me comment on your answer.

Comment: This answer worked for me. Thanks! I.e. copying the iCal url from meetup, then adding it manually to Google Calendar.
When I tried to just click the _Google calendar_ option instead of the ical option on Meetup, it said _"This email address isn't associated with an active Google Calendar account: https://www.meetup.com/events/ical/..../going. Please check the email address and try again."_
I think I also changed the "webcal://" to "http://" but don't know if that was necesary.

Comment: It does still work, you must make sure you use the **From URL** submenu.

Answer (score 5):

On your meetup home page, click the 'Add to' link above Your meetup calendar.  Then choose All my Meetups or My Yes RSVPs.  Then click the Google Calendar icon.

This will bring up your Google Calendar with a prompt asking: Do you want to add this calendar?  Click Yes and all your meetups should now be added to your calendar now and going forward.

See also:
[Can I publish a feed of my Meetups to appear on my Google Calendar?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/3628/can-i-publish-a-feed-of-my-meetups-to-appear-on-my-google-calendar)

Comment: I think the Asker would like to be able to have the events automagically appear without such intervention.

Answer (score 3):

## Good news!

You can do this for *all* groups fortunately.

## Instructions

First you need Firefox with Firebug extension installed.

Then you need to open Firebug (default by F12), open Editor tab and paste that code:

```
$(".card-photo").each(function(i,v){

var x = $(v).attr('href')
x = x.split("/")
var xpre = "http://api.meetup.com/"
var xaft = "/upcoming.ical?key="
var key = "YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"
var what = x[3]

var link = xpre + what + xaft + key

console.log(link)

})
```

Where your API key can be found here:

https://secure.meetup.com/meetup_api/key/

Then run this script, and on output tab you'll have list of iCalendar links to subscribe.

[Source: http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/feeds/](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/feeds/)

Answer (score 2):

I used the link on my meetup home page and it worked just fine.  I used the option to only sync the RSVPs.  Once you go to your Google calendar you can use the drop down next to My Calendar and choose settings.  Then you can go in and set how your notifications and reminders are delivered.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I made it work on my google calendar. You go to the main page of meetup. the URL is just meetup.com. Then you look to your lower right, there should be a small monthly calendar, under the calendar there is an icon with a small arrow that says export to, click on it and the choose Google Calendar. And that's it!

Answer (score 1):

Now you have to go to the **calendar** page and choose the **iCal** in the bottom (then either you open it or copy/paste it to Google Calendar for instance).

It's quite annoying to do that for all meetups...

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get this to work on GCal either (first time worked, but it wouldn't update).

You could however export the subscription calendar link, and manually add it to your calendar - this will create a sync'ed calendar that you will **never** have to manually update

1. Go to meetup.com home page with the calendar widget on the right
2. Export To -> iCal Calendar
3. If the Calendar app on your machine doesn't open automatically, copy the link in (2) and import the feed in whatever Calendar program you're using, the link should look like: `webcal://www.meetup.com/events/ical/.....`

I've successfully tested this on a Mac's Calendar app and added it as an iPhone subscribed calendar (Settings -> Mail, contacts, calendar -> Add -> Other -> Add Subscribed calendar -> paste webcal link from (3) above).